# GrpcServerRule Not finding implementation

Tags: kotlin, grpc, grpc-java

I am trying to write some unit test for one of the GRPC service.

I am using the GrpcServerRule to do so.

Once I run the test, it seems that the implementation of the service is not loaded properly. I don't manage to find why.

Here is the code for the test.

```
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class CreateListTest {

// Workaround for public
@get:Rule  val serverRule: GrpcServerRule = GrpcServerRule().directExecutor()

@Before
fun setup() {
    serverRule.serviceRegistry.addService(ShopperServerImplementation())
}


@Test
fun testCreateListValidRequest() {
    val request = CreateListRequest.newBuilder()
            .setName("a test list")
            .setAuthorId(25)
            .addAuthorizedUsers(12)
            .build()
    val reply = ShopperServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(serverRule.channel).createList(request)
    assertEquals(45, reply.createdListId)
}

}
```

Here is the code for the service implementation.

```
class ShopperServerImplementation : ShopperGRPCGrpc.ShopperGRPCImplBase() {
override fun createList(request: CreateListRequest, responseObserver: StreamObserver<CreateListReply>) {
    val reply = CreateListReply.newBuilder().setCreatedListId(80).build()
    responseObserver.onNext(reply)
    responseObserver.onCompleted()
}
}
```

Here is the log from the test result

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNIMPLEMENTED: Method not found: shopper.ShopperService/createList

at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:227)
at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:208)
at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:141)
at com.kevinlegoff.shopper.io.ShopperServiceGrpc$ShopperServiceBlockingStub.createList(ShopperServiceGrpc.java:156)
at com.kevinlegoff.shopper.server.CreateListTest.testCreateListValidRequest(CreateListTest.kt:35)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:48)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: I don't know Kotlin. But it seems that should work. Maybe it's some Kotlin-specific interaction with JUnit?

Comment: Yeah I don't know neither. I am writing the test in java just to try out. The real server and client are working in Kotlin.

Comment: Did not got any luck with JAVA neither. Server is still in Kotlin so it could still mean some inter-portability issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a good clean of the project makes everything run as expected. Not sure what happen. Will investigate and post an issue on github if I encounter it again.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer, as you may run into intermittent issues with your solution-- it may not properly release resources when the test is completed.

Comment: You may also want to look at using Kotlin Test with JUnit 5 instead of JUnit 4 directly, there are advantages there with newer framework releases supporting the new extension system (replacing RunWith): https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-kotlin

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@JvmField` annotation for your rule field. You may also run into issues with the gRPC service not being properly cleaned up. So another approach would be to have a separate class with a clean-up rule, such as:

```
class LoopbackServer {
    val client: ShopperServiceGrpc.ShopperServiceBlockingStub
    private val yourService = ShopperServiceController()

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val grpcCleanup = GrpcCleanupRule()

    init {
        // Generate a unique in-process server name.
        val serverName = InProcessServerBuilder.generateName()

        // Create a server, add service, start, and register for automatic graceful shutdown.
        grpcCleanup.register(InProcessServerBuilder.forName(serverName).directExecutor()
                .addService(yourService).build().start())

        client = ShopperServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(
                // Create a client channel and register for automatic graceful shutdown.
                grpcCleanup.register(InProcessChannelBuilder.forName(serverName).directExecutor().build()))
    }
}
```

Then you can reference that in your test class:

```
class CreateListTest {
    private val server = LoopbackServer()
    private val client = server.client

    @Test
    fun `When service called with a valid List request, it succeeds`() {
        val request = CreateListRequest.newBuilder()
            .setName("a test list")
            .setAuthorId(25)
            .addAuthorizedUsers(12)
            .build()
        val reply = client.createList(request)
        assertEquals(45, reply.createdListId)
    }

}
```